# Where is a good place to dispose of the SqlConnection object created in AddDbContext? (.Net Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get Azure's Managed Identity authentication to work with my app that I will be deploying on Azure App Service to connect to an Azure SQL Server.

After looking through some examples and sample code I am attempting the following implementation:

```
services.AddDbContext<MainContext>(optionsBuilder =>
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    connection.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
});
```

Where would be the right place to dispose of this SqlConnection? Is there a better way to implement this AccessToken set up?

Comment: Have you tried with `Using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection()) {  } `?

Comment: @GuidoG as I am registering the context at that point, if a using statement was used there, it would dispose the SqlConnection before it is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try by first registering your context as normal:

```
services.AddDbContext<MainContext>(builder => 
               builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext), this is registered as "Scoped" by default, so the connection will be automatically opened and closed on each request.

> The AddDbContext extension method registers DbContext types with a
>   scoped lifetime by default.

Then, retrieve the registered context and add the access token as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<MainContext>(serviceProvider => {
      var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainContext>();  
      var connection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection() as SqlConnection;
      if(connection == null) {
          return dbContext;
      }
      connection.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
      return dbContext;
});
```

Now, on every request, the connection is created and disposed for you and the access token will be retrieved.

A different way (perhaps cleaner), would be to inherit from your context and add the token in the constructor:

```
public class ContextWithAccessToken : MainDbContext 
{
    public ContextWithAccessToken(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        var connection = (SqlConnection)this.Database.GetDbConnection();
        connection.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
    }
}
```

Then just register this context instead:

```
services.AddDbContext<ContextWithAccessToken>(builder => 
               builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, let me take a look. I like your creation of a subclass context to wrap it up, not adding more code to the Startup class.

Comment: I'm not sure that the ContextWithAccessToken is a great way to go. All thats happened is configuration has moved from the class its supposed to be configured in, to the class itself; and in the process made it more difficult to mock/unit test the DbContext because it now has an internal dependency on something in its constructor? At the very least, AzureServiceTokenProvider should be injected into the constructor to at least allow it to be mocked, and follow the IOC pattern

Comment: I proposed both options, using DI or inheriting. The DbContext can still be mocked, though.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to dispose of the connection. Its attached/configured against the DbContext and the context manages disposal. What you have there should work fine.

Comment: No, the way he has configured it, the connection will not be disposed, if you create it, you dispose it ;-)

Comment: I was originally thinking that, as I had not performed an ".Open()" on the SqlConnection. But I believe it may have underlying resources such as connection pools that need to be disposed of.